# How do I get the currently focused element in HtmlUnit

Tags: java, htmlunit

In my javascript I did

```
document.getElementById(myID).focus();
```

to focus the element.

Rather than trying to traverse through the DOM tree, I was wondering if I can simply say something like

```
var element = (HtmlTextInput) webClient.getActieWindow().getFocusedElement();
```

but I can't seem to find it in the API

Answer (score 0):

I needed the page as well to get the element

```
HtmlTextInput textInput =
 (HtmlTextInput) ((HtmlPage) webClient
    .getCurrentWindow()
    .getEnclosedPage())
  .getFocusedElement();
```